# Recent change in privileges

Tags: support, tagging, reputation, privileges

Was there a change in the privileges recently on the main side and meta or is it me?

I came recently over 3k reputation which made me visit the [privileges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges) page again. There are now two additional entries for *protect questions* (15k) and *trusted user* (20k) which weren't there last time.
Are they new or are they just displayed for people with enough reputation?

Also, did the reputation changed to edit tag wiki pages on meta? I was able to create the tag wiki for [syntax-highlighting](/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) a short while ago, but now it tells me that 20k are needed to change it. (I just wanted to remove the back-ticks from the excerpt.)

**Update 2**: You can "approve tag wiki edits" on the main site with 5k now, but I couldn't find the limit for the actual edit. Maybe you have to approve your own edits then :-).

Comment: So at the moment only mods can make/approve tag wiki changes. :(

Comment: @Caramdir: You can still suggest it. It's not nice, but it's good enough.

Comment: See also [this post over at meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72874/155585) for tag wiki suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find the answer to all questions of this type in the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/155585) over at meta.stackoverflow. And yes, the new privileges were introduced on the 9th of February.

Comment: Thanks Hendrik. But I have to say I liked the old system for tag wikis better.

Comment: @Martin: I didn't voice any _opinion_ about the recent changes; just told you were to look `:-)`

Comment: I know, I just needed a shoulder to cry on :-)

Comment: 20k is a _lot_ of reputation: I wonder if this makes any real sense away from the main SO site?

Comment: I also notice thinks like 'votes of -1 or lower', which might make sense on the SO main site, but here we agreed that nothing should ever be voted below -1. (They also need to edit the 'faq' page to show the new privileges: currently they are not mentioned.)

Comment: @Joseph: I'm pretty sure they won't make any special adjustments for tex.sx. (I've got some experience from the discussion about the spoiler feature `:-(`) But this 'votes of -1 or lower' is OK, isn't it? Just ignore the 'or lower' part!

Comment: @Hendrik. I was just commenting that some of the changes won't map that well from the main SO site to the new sites. Doesn't mean that anything will happen :-)

Comment: @Joseph: Interestingly, I could still edit the tikz tag wiki. So 20k can't be the only possible requirement.

Comment: @Caramdir: Was this today? Before 9.2. you only needed be under the top answers of the tag.

Comment: @Martin: It was after the change. But testing now, I see that they have closed that hole. :(

Comment: @Joseph: Now it's there in the 'faq'.